# PhpStorm + Xdebug + CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, phpstorm, xdebug

I've coded a new project into PhpStorm using CakePHP framework. I've installed Xdebug following this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ankurk91/22e4a07be552790a9d6a063ee1bace05) but I'm not able to debug my code.

If I run validation script into `Run >> Web Server Debug Validation` in PhpStorm, I get every time which you see below

[image: PhpStorm Web Server Debug Validation]

I can't understand warning "Remote debug is not enabled" because it's configured as enabled in my php.ini

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE & RESOLUTION**

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/ankurk91/22e4a07be552790a9d6a063ee1bace05) is not correct for me!
I have edited `/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini` in this way

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 512
xdebug.file_link_format = phpstorm://open?%f:%l
```

and then in Run configuration I've put a `PHP Web Application` config

Comment: 1) Please provide `php_info()` output captured via browser -- I need top header table (where it shows PHP info + xdebug version) + dedicated xdebug section. 2) What php.ini file you have edited (give full path)? Right now it's possible that you have more than 1 PHP installed .. or it uses different php.ini (one for CLI and one for Apache/web server). Therefore it may mean that you need to edit different php.ini.

Comment: You can click on (...) button after the text to get information about what is required. Most probably it is about https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_enable.